# Razor bad asp-route link generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I try to make a pagination system. However I have problem with my code about razor asp-route.

Here is the controller:

```
[Route("blog")]
public class BlogController : BaseController
{
    [Route("{categorySlug}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Category([FromRoute] string categorySlug, [FromQuery] int page)
    {
          return View();
    }
}
```

And here is the razor tag helper used to generate the url:

```
 <a class="link" asp-action="Category" asp-controller="Blog"
    asp-route-categorySlug="some-slug"
    asp-route-page="1">1</a>
```

I expected the generated href to be:

```
/blog/some-slug?page=1
```

But I have the following url instead:

```
/Blog/Category?categorySlug=some-slug&page=1
```

Is there a way to generate the wanted url with `asp-route` ?

Comment: Change to `[HttpGet("{categorySlug}")]`

Comment: Same problem. When I remove the `asp-route-page="1"` it generate the good url (`/blog/some-slug`) but when adding  `asp-route-page="1"`  everything breaks.

Comment: do you have any other methods on this controller?  You may want to try `[Route("{*categorySlug}")]` as a catch-all-route to avoid having the routing add the method to the url (it's doing it because your route has no unique identifier for it to know to use this method).

Comment: No, I removed all other methods to do the test @ErikPhilips

Comment: And the catch-all-route not works. I forgot to say that my Startup.cs file look like this:

            `app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });`.
If I remove this route, no url is generated at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congifure route template using `app.UseMvc` in `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "BlogRoute",
        template: "blog/{categorySlug}");

    //.. other routes
});
```

Update your link to use this route

```
<a class="link" asp-route="BlogRoute" 
    asp-route-categorySlug="some-slug"
    asp-route-page="1">1</a>
```

**A bit modified solution using action and controller names**

Route configuration

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BlogRoute",
    template: "blog/{categorySlug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Category" });
```

Link

```
<a class="link" asp-action="Category" asp-controller="Blog"
    asp-route-categorySlug="some-slug"
    asp-route-page="1">1</a>
```

**Failed attempt**

One may wonder what if we use attribute routing and force tag helper to use this route (by setting `asp-route`)

```
[Route("blog")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    [Route("{categorySlug}", Name = "BlogRoute")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Category([FromRoute] string categorySlug, [FromQuery] int page) {
//..
}
```

and link code

```
<a class="link" asp-route="BlogRoute" 
    asp-route-categorySlug="some-slug"
    asp-route-page="1">1</a>
```

In this case `page` value is completely ignored and resulting url is `/blog/some-slug`

**Note**

Various tests have shown that code in your question worked fine actually and you don't need to add a route in `app.UseMvc`. For example the following link

```
<a class="link" asp-route="BlogRoute" 
    asp-route-value="val1"
    asp-route-data="info"
    asp-route-categorySlug="some-slug">1</a>
```

generates this url

```
/blog/some-slug?value=val1&data=info
```

But if you add `asp-route-page="1"` it is just ignored and output is the same. It turns out that url genering excludes parameters with specific names such as `page`, `action` and `controller` (`area` works fine, possibly there are more keywords). So my solution is just a workaround specifically for `page` parameter name. If you try to add `action` or `controller` parameter my solution will just generate stub value `/path`.

So it means you can just use some other name than `page` like this

```
<a class="link" asp-route="BlogRoute"
    asp-route-categorySlug="some-slug"
    asp-route-pageNum="1">1</a>
```

And bind `page` parameter to `pageNum` name

```
[Route("{categorySlug}", Name = "BlogRoute")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Category([FromRoute] string categorySlug, [FromQuery(Name = "pageNum")] int page)
```